# How to set a background image in android

Tags: android

Im very new to this android development.I just started to create a hello world application.

I tried to set a background image and it is working fine.When i tried to add a text on the image it is not working.

I tried in the way below.Can anyone please help me where im going wrong.

in

Main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="@drawable/andriod" 
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" 
    android:gravity="center_vertical"> 

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

</LinearLayout>
```

HelloActivity.java

```
  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.widget.TextView;
  //import android.widget.ImageView;    

    public class HelloActivity extends Activity {
    //    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    //    @Override
    //    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    //    }    

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
       @Override

       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

           TextView tv = new TextView(this);              
           tv.setText("This is the first andorid app");          
           setContentView(R.layout.main);         
       }
}
```

When running it is showing the background image but "This is the first andorid app" is not showing.

Hoping for your help

Comment: @ishhhh: You are setting text in TextView tv, but not adding this tv in the layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must select the TextView in your layout file with its unique ID and then set it properties. But in ur code, u just create a text view with the text and not place it into the view.

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
tv.setText("Your text here");
```

Comment: can you please tell me how can i  run the downloaded android sample projects in the sdk.when i download the sample projects im not able to run it.can you please help me

Comment: you're welcome. if you have eclipse installed, in the android project wizard, there is an option you'll see that opens sample projects directly in Eclipse.

Answer (score 5):

First you need to give the textview an id in XML file, so that it can be accessed in the Java source **(note the android:id attribute in following XML)**;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="@drawable/andriod" 
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" 
    android:gravity="center_vertical"> 

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Now set the text in this textview;

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewId(R.id.textView);

    textView.setText("This is the first andorid app");
}
```

Note, how the textview declared in XML is accessed from here.

It is not

```
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
```

this will create a new textview. But what we need here is

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewId(R.id.textView);
```

this will refer to the textview declared in XML file above.

Comment: Thankyou for your detailed explanation.it is very helpful for a beginner like me.Hope for your help in future also

Comment: :can you please tell me how can i run the downloaded android sample projects in the sdk.when i download the sample projects im not able to run it.can you please help me

Comment: @mudasir suppose i download a sample project from net.now how can i run it in the eclipse.im not able to find any project file in that folder.hope you understand

Comment: Can't you import it in eclipse..?

Answer (score 4):

You need to fetch the TextView from the current content view ..
add these lines after setContentView(..), also add an id to your text view in the layout

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(...)
```